# using mailR gives an error: Argument 'from' should be a of length one

Tags: r

I am new to R and trying to create a function that would send an email.
Getting an error:

```
Error: Argument 'from' should be a of length one.
```

"from" is for sure a single email.   So what is that even mean?

My code:

```
  library(mailR)

send_mailR_email <- function(from, to, cc, subject, body) {
  
  # Set up SMTP server details
  smtp <- list(host.name = "mysmtp.com", port = 25,
               user.name = "myusername",
               passwd = "mypassw", ssl = TRUE)
  
  # Create the email
  email <- list(
    from = from,
    to = to,
    cc = cc,
    subject = subject,
    body = body
  )
  
  
  send.mail(email, smtp = smtp)
}


# Execute function 
send_mailR_email(
  from = "fromemail@mail.com",
  to = c("toemail@mail.com"),
  cc = c("toemail@mail.com"),
  subject = "Test email subject",
  body = "Test email body"
)
```